# using the data in form in a function

Tags: javascript, html

So basically I want to take the data in the form and use it in a function.

HTML:

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="Ordering()">
  
    <input id="X" type="checkbox">
    <input id="Y" type="checkbox">
   
   <input type="submit" value="order">
   <input type="reset">
   
 
  
  </form>
```

Java Script:

```html
function Ordering()
{
 alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
 
 if(document.getElementById('X')==true;)
 {
  action='whatsapp://send?abid=&text=';
 }
 if(document.getElementById('Y')==true;)
 {
 action='ailto:pizza@manheten.co.il?subject=Pizza%20order&body=123';
}
```

but i cant activate the script at all... i tried to use an alert to see if its even getting there ... but with no success .. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some typos and you need to use value to get the value and compare as follows:

```js
function Ordering() {
  alert('hello');
  if (document.getElementById('X').value) {
    action = 'whatsapp://send?abid=&text=';
  }
  if (document.getElementById('Y').value) {
    action = 'ailto:pizza@manheten.co.il?subject=Pizza%20order&body=123';
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" onsubmit="Ordering()">
  <input id="X" type="checkbox">
  <input id="Y" type="checkbox">
  <input type="submit" value="order">
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment,  but my first problem was that i cant get to the function at all... when i click on the submmit button nothing happens

Comment: @ItamarNahum, the function  is being called in the snippet. Run the snippet.

Comment: I see thank you, I guess there's a problem with my setup than cause in my notepad it's not working

Comment: @ItamarNahum, it is because you had typos, you can just copy paste what i have written, should work. And also if it works , do tick it correct.

Comment: thanks its going into the function- but I can't get the function actually work I want to sent an email if the checkbox of the email is Y is checked